# Best practice: Is it more efficient to replace each element or to check and replace only what has changed?

Tags: javascript

This question stems from a conundrum I am facing in Javascript, though a more general scientific response would be extremely helpful.

If an object or array is being iterated over for another purpose—and it is known that only one element of interest has changed which can be acted upon for manipulation—is it best to:

- Simply replace every element with new data to reflect the change
- Rigorously check each element and replace only that which has changed

(In this example, heights of all bars of a graph are being adjusted—as they are relative—though only one textual piece of information is targeted for change.)

```
Array.from(result['data']).forEach(row => {
    const bar = document.getElementById('bar-' + row['date']);
    bar.style.height = 'calc(1.6rem + ' + row['percentage'] + '%)';
    bar.firstChild.textContent = row['distance'];
});
```

Or:

```
Array.from(result['data']).forEach(row => {
    const bar = document.getElementById('bar-' + row['date']);
    bar.style.height = 'calc(1.6rem + ' + row['percentage'] + '%)';
    if (bar.firstChild.textContent !== row['distance']) bar.firstChild.textContent = row['distance'];
});
```

I suppose this is a question that exposes my ignorance and it has made it difficult for me to research a conclusion: Is it more computationally exhausting to replace all elements when a difference is known to exist somewhere in the set, or is it cheaper to seek out the offending individual and change only that value?

(Setting timers, i.e. console.timeEnd(), has proved inconclusive.)

Any education would be throughly appreciated. I can't get my head around it.

Comment: You really could have just thought about this one, the functions are exactly the same except that one has a conditional check, meaning it's more code so more time.

Comment: @chbchb55 That's not true. More code does not necessarily mean more time, and DOM lookup is *separate* from DOM assignment.

Comment: @CertainPerformance You're right, more code does not necessarily mean more time, **however**, in this case the rest of the code is exactly the same except for that single `if` statement, so it will take more time, logically.

Comment: @chbchb55 No, because lookup is *fundamentally different* from assignment. What if lookup was near instant and assignment took some CPU cycles? What if assignment was near instant and lookup took some CPU cycles? The answer would vary. See my answer below - it *does* vary between browsers. For some, lookup is more costly, and for others, assignment is more costly. Sometimes, the `if` check can be *faster* than the situation with no `if` check.

Comment: @CertainPerformance It might vary slightly, but if it's running a check and then running the code it's going to take more time than just running the code.

Comment: @chbchb55 It's more than "slightly" - again, see my answer. Depending on the browser, it could be the difference between 5 times faster and many orders of magnitude slower. If the `if` statement is not fulfilled, there is no code to run. Lookup does *not* take the same time as assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the browser.

On Chrome and Opera, at least, plain assignment without checking looks to be more performant than looking up the existing text, even without possible assignment on top of looking up the existing text, by an order of around 3x:

(warning: running the following code will *block* your browser for some time, only press "Run" if you're sure)

```js
const fn1 = () => {
  const bar = document.querySelector('#bar');
  for (let i = 0; i < 9999999; i++) bar.textContent = 'bar1';
};
const fn2 = () => {
  const bar = document.querySelector('#bar');
  for (let i = 0; i < 9999999; i++) {
    // The following condition will never be fulfilled:
    if (bar.textContent !== 'bar2') bar.textContent = 'bar2';
  }
};

const now0 = performance.now();
fn1();
const now1 = performance.now();
fn2();
const now2 = performance.now();
console.log(now1 - now0);
console.log(now2 - now1);
```

```html
<div id="bar"></div>
```

On the other hand, on Firefox 56, the lookup seems to take next to no time at all (whereas assignment *is* computationally expensive)

But this is only really something to worry about if you have *tons and tons* of elements. Unless you're dealing with thousands or tens of thousands of elements, it's not something worth optimizing for.

Comment: This is exactly the type of experimentation I was hoping to find. Thank you. Though I am still curious as to the scientific thought: What would be best practice in a more responsible language in a more crucial application?

Comment: well in safari fn2 is 5 times faster (4636 vs 882)

Comment: @ethet It would probably be better to have the current text content in a *variable* (set whenever the actual textContent changes), that way you don't have to check with the DOM itself beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to check if the property already has the value you're assigning to it. The browser will determine if the value actually changed and handle it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Since in your example you have already called DOM method `getElementById` which is the slowest part checking the property is way faster than performing a change to it. So it's always better to **keep DOM-manipulations as little as possible**.

**UPD** @CertainPerformance's test shows that performance varies amongst browsers =)